# Can a generic.GenericForeignKey() field be Null?

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating an object which tracks changes (Updates) regarding the creation, updating and deletion of other so called `UUIDSyncable` objects in the database.

This involves any object which extends the `UUIDSyncable` classes's `save()` and `delete()` methods being overriden, in such a way that it creates a new `Update` object recording the action (either insert, update or delete) and originally a `models.CharField(max_length=64)` field specifying the UUID pk of of the of `UUIDSyncable` objects.

At this point I wanted to update the implementation to use Django's `generic.GenericForeignKey()` field in stead of my single character field. This would enable be to access the object about which the update is being recorded in a much simpler way.

My problem arrises when you wish to delete an object and store that as an `Update` object, as you know Django preforms a cascade delete on the `UUIDSyncable` object being deleted, deleting all the previous `Update` records (which is not wanted).

When the `UUIDSyncable` object has been deleted in my original implementation, each `Update` object would still retain the UUID to inform external parties about its deletion. My first solution to emulate this was to set `content_object = None` just before deleting the object on all the `Update` objects, thus preventing the deletion cascade.

It seams that `generic.GenericForeignKey()` cannot be set to allow `NULL` values. Is there a way to do this, or if not how can a standard `CharField` holding a UUID primary key and a sperate `CharField` holding the model name be used in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Perhaps you need to set null=True on the underlying `content_type` and `object_id` fields that make up the generic foreign key.

Comment: I have tried allowing content_type to be null but not object_id, as I always wish to keep the value the object id (charField PK is this case) has for reference later on (even after the object it specifies) has been deleted. This I remember did not seam to allow me to ascertain my goal.

Answer (score 54):

For the lazy/pragmatic:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...other fields...
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Comment: I love it when I Google and stumble across my own answer...d'oh

Comment: `content_type` & `object_id` are de default names, you dont even need to set them as arguments `content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()` would be enough

Comment: @yamm you have to set them to explicitly have blank=True / null=True on those fields so that the content_object can be null, which is what the question is about.

Comment: @MarkChackerian yes i konw ;-) thats why i said that you dont need to set `content_type` & `object_id` as **arguments** because they are default. You define `content_type` & `object_id` and then you simply do `content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()`

Comment: It is also advisable to set `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` constraint to `content_type` since default is `CASCADE`.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard thanks -- I have updated my answer, as `on_delete` is now required for Django 2.0

Comment: @yamm -- so annoying when people rely on the default field names instead of making it explicit. I'm happy your advice was ignored.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried setting `null=True` on the `GenericForeignKey`? Generic foreign keys aren't a concept that is recognised by the low-level database application (i.e. MySQL, SQLite, etc.) so you should be able to specify that the field be null.

`null=True` on a database field in Django signifies that the database field representing that data is *allowed* to be empty, whereas `blank=True` tells the Django forms/model validation that the field is OK to be left empty by the user (or you, through the admin interface). Therefore, you might need to use both to achieve what you're after.